# Struts2 project loading very slowly on tomcat8 version

Tags: struts2, migration, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have a Struts project with Struts version 2.3.

The project is very well working in Tomcat 7.

Recently, due to the application hacked by some Chinese ip, we found the system is hacked by some Tomcat vulnerabilities, so we plan to upgrade the server to Tomcat 8, but when we compare Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 7 the application loads very slowly on Tomcat 8.

Is there any compatibility issue between Tomcat8 and Struts 2.3 ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify which Struts 2.3 version; consider that, if the vulnerability you're referring to is [S2-046](https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-046.html), upgrading the Struts2 version to `2.3.32` (or `2.5.10.1`) is enough, there's no need to change the Tomcat version.

That said, if you want to migrate the WebApp to a newer Tomcat, I remember there were problems with early versions of Tomcat 8, and BTW I strongly suggest you to migrate to *at least* **Tomcat 8.5**, which is a differen AS from Tomcat 8, not just another 8.x version.

Comment: Okay i will check this.